# How get data from two tables with null relations

Tags: neo4j

I have two nodes. Lvl1 and Phone. I want return data as on pic

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want all Lvl1's and the phone(s) they have:

```
MATCH (n:Lvl1) //all Lvl1's
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[:HAVE_PHONE]->(s:Phone) //Optionally find the HAVE_PHONE relation
RETURN n,s
```